# PyVmomi add NIC with unconnected dvs ('config.distributedVirtualSwitch' is Unset)

Tags: python, vmware, nic, vcenter, pyvmomi

I am using the code below in order to add a NIC configured with `DistributedVirtualSwitch` to an existing VM (via pyVmomi):

```
def __AddNIC(si, vmconf_dict, network_name):
    vm = __get_vm(si, vmconf_dict)
    print " Network label : " + network_name

    devices = []
    nicspec = vim.vm.device.VirtualDeviceSpec()
    nicspec.operation = vim.vm.device.VirtualDeviceSpec.Operation.add
    nicspec.device = vim.vm.device.VirtualVmxnet3()
    nicspec.device.wakeOnLanEnabled = True
    nicspec.device.deviceInfo = vim.Description()
    nicspec.device.connectable = vim.vm.device.VirtualDevice.ConnectInfo()
    nicspec.device.connectable.startConnected = True
    nicspec.device.connectable.allowGuestControl = True

    network_objref = _get_mor_by_property(si, vim.dvs.DistributedVirtualPortgroup, network_name)
    dswitch_port_connection = vim.dvs.PortConnection(
        portgroupKey=network_objref.key,
        switchUuid=network_objref.config.distributedVirtualSwitch.uuid
    )
    nicspec.device.backing = vim.vm.device.VirtualEthernetCard.DistributedVirtualPortBackingInfo()
    nicspec.device.backing.port = dswitch_port_connection

    devices.append(nicspec)
    vmconf = vim.vm.ConfigSpec(deviceChange=devices)
    task = vm.ReconfigVM_Task(vmconf)
    tasks.wait_for_tasks(si, [task])
```

I'm getting the following **exception**:

> switchUuid=network_objref.config.distributedVirtualSwitch.uuid
>       AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'uuid'

After examination of Vcenter Managed Objects(via [mob](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.wssdk.pg.doc_50%2FPG_ChB_Using_MOB.20.1.html)) it appears that
**some of the *`DistributedVirtualPortgroup`* object references does have that (*`VmwareDistributedVirtualSwitch`*) property, while others have this property *`Unset`*.**

[image: VmwareDistributedVirtualSwitch Set]

[image: VmwareDistributedVirtualSwitch Unset]

I've tried multiple ways to work around that, such as:

- Setting:
  `switchUuid=None` which yielded:

  > `TypeError: Required field "switchUuid" not provided (not @optional)`
- Setting:
  `dswitch_port_connection = None` which yielded:

  > `TypeError: Required field "port" not provided (not @optional)`

**Note:** When I'm using `VMware WebClient` to configure the above it works perfectly.

**Question:** how can I make adding a NIC like this work?

Comment: What version of vSphere are you using, and which pyVmomi version are you using?

Comment: @MichaelRice vSphere: 5.5.0 Build 1879799, Pyvmomi: 5.5.0.2014.1.1

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Eventually after severe experimentation, Setting:

```
dswitch_port_connection = '<Unset>'
```

Solved the issue and resulted in adding NIC with configured but unconnected DVS.

Answer (score 2):

Check your user permissions. Do you have System.Read privileges on the portgroup?

> Distributed virtual switch that the portgroup is defined on. This
>   property should always be set unless the user's setting does not have
>   System.Read privilege on the object referred to by this property.

https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi/blob/master/docs/vim/DistributedVirtualSwitch.rst